# Calculate the value of a norm of two matrix (is $\Omega(A,B)=1$?)

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-norms

Let $A$ and $B$ two bounded operators on a complex Hilbert space $E$. We define
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Omega(A,B)=\sup\left \{ \| \alpha A+\beta B\| \,;\;\; \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C},\; |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\leq 1 \right\}.
 \end{eqnarray*}
We can prove that $\Omega(A,B)$ defines a norm on the bounded operators on $E\times E$.

> I want to calculate $\Omega(A,B)$ when
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

We can check that
\begin{align*}
  \Omega(A,B)&= \sup_{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\leq 1}\sup_{|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2\leq 1} \Big\|\begin{pmatrix} 0&\beta&\alpha\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\Big\| \\
&=\sup_{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\leq 1}\sup_{|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2\leq 1} |\alpha z+\beta y|
 \end{align*}

I think we can proceed as follows
\begin{align*}
|\alpha z+\beta y|
&\leq \sqrt{\left(|\alpha| |z|+|\beta| |y|\right)^2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{\left(|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2 \right)\left(|y|^2 +|z|^2 \right)}\\
&\leq \sqrt{\left(|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2 \right)\left(|x|^2 +|y|^2+ |z|^2\right)}\\
&\leq 1
\end{align*}
So,
$$\Omega(A,B)\leq1.$$

> Is $\Omega(A,B)=1$?

Comment: Why not use $(|\alpha||z|+|\beta||y|)^2≤(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)(|z|^2+|y|^2)≤(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)(|z|^2+|y|^2+|x|^2)≤1$ ? which use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I used it of course but my problem is the converse inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing a lower bound for norms which involve a supremum is usually done by evaluating the supremum at a "suitable" point. In this case one possible way is
$$
\Omega(A,B)=\sup_{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\leq1}\sup_{|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2\leq1}|\alpha z+\beta y|\overset{(x,y,z)=(0,0,1)}\geq\sup_{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\leq1}|\alpha|\overset{(\alpha,\beta)=(1,0)}\geq 1
$$
which -- together with the inequality $\Omega(A,B)\leq 1$ which you already proved -- shows $\Omega(A,B)=1$ as desired.

Answer (score -2):

Think of the combinations $\alpha A+\beta B$ as vectors on the space of linear operators. Now think of the operator norm on the space generated by $A$ and $B$. Can you write it or calculate it for the aforementioned combinations? Remember that in a finite dimensional (in this case two dimensional) Banach space you can write all the possible norms of that space.

Comment: I think your answer may be as a comment since I tried and I hope to get help concerning my calculations. Thanks